# Yammer Widget Using cURL

Tags: curl, oauth

I'm trying to make a widget for my home page which will automatically pull from a yammer feed, much like a desktop client, using cURL (PHP).  I can't find any examples anywhere, though.  Has anyone managed to get through OAuth verification this way?

Answer (score 1):

I'm working on something similar, will answer you more thoroughly later, though here is a brief.

1. Once you requested both the
   consumer-key and consumer-secret,
   make a request to 
   https://www.yammer.com/oauth/request_token, I could not get it to work with HMAC-SHA1 so use PLAINTEXT. The oauth_signature is a the consumer_secret with & appended to it : http://oauth.net/core/1.0/#anchor22
2. With oauth_token and oauth_token_secret make a request to 
   https://www.yammer.com/oauth/request_token with the oauth_token
3. You will get a code to authorize your application, this is the    oauth_verifier
4. Now make another request to https://www.yammer.com/oauth/authorize with the unathorized_token
5. Finally make a request to https://www.yammer.com/oauth/access_token with your access token...

Reading these was useful:

http://github.com/lemonad/python-yammer-oauth
http://github.com/psanford/emacs-yammer

Comment: This might be helpful at least to help you get started with the OAuth process, http://danielmiessler.com/blog/federated-id-openid-and-oauth-a-web-authentication-primer

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  Unfortunately, this project got scrapped and I never checked back for an answer.  I hope it helps someone else....

Answer (score 0):

well here is the working example http://www.tutorialjinni.com/2011/04/yammer-api-example.html with source code.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Always make sure and post your code here as well. These questions are for future reference and that link might not always be there.